# Cloud Foundry: Credentials were rejected

Tags: cloud-foundry

I'm having trouble with cf login. Whenever I try to login i get the following error:

```
Credentials were rejected, please try again.
```

Now I'm Aware that this is a known [issue](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/cli#known-issues). But even with alternatives, I always get the same message.

What I've tried so far:

```
Git CMD; cmd.exe; Powershell;
cf login -u mail@adress.com; (and different variations)
cf auth "Mail@Adress.com" "MyPassword";
```

What else is there I can try or what am I missing?

Comment: have you tried just `cf login` works for me on windows 10

Comment: Yes, have tried. Same issue...

Comment: @Tobe Have you set PCF API Endpoint? If you're using PWS, you might require to set as `api.run.pivotal.io`

Comment: @KumareshBabu I was able to do it with --sso, no idea why the other way didn't work. Company blocking me in some way, anyway thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `cf login` or `cf auth` and specify a username/password, you are attempting to authenticate with UAA using a standard password based authentication. If your company uses single sign-on (i.e. SSO), this will *not* work.

When your company uses SSO, you need to run `cf login -sso` (that's it, no other flags). In this case, the cf cli will give you a link to click. You'll go to this link in your browser and it will display a one-time password. The cf cli will then prompt you for the one-time password, type it in and the cli will use that to log you in with your company's SSO system.

Again, if your company has set up SSO you *must* use the `cf login -sso` option to login. As far as I know, there's no way to tell from the cf cli if your company requires SSO, but you can tell if you go to `login.system_domain` in your browser (where `system_domain` the the DNS entry set up for CF).  When you go to that page, you'll see the login form and when SSO is set up the bottom of the form will have a link that says "click here to login with SSO" or something like that. That link only shows up when SSO is enabled.

Comment: Interesting, didn't know that. Thanks for your answer, it was the solution!